# Intent flags not working when calling createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()

Tags: android, keyguard

I'm having trouble trying to get some custom behavior from the KeyguardManager API, particularly the createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent() method. According to the docs, it's used to:

> Get an intent to prompt the user to confirm credentials (pin, pattern
>   or password) for the current user of the device. The caller is
>   expected to launch this activity using startActivityForResult(Intent,
>   int) and check for RESULT_OK if the user successfully completes the
>   challenge.

From what I can tell, there's no mention of restrictions on *how* you start this activity, yet setting flags like Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY seems to make no difference. Am I right in assuming that Google locked down some functionality for security reasons? If not, what am I missing?